# Query to show the scraps of User that has logined and his friends?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created 3 tables:

- `Login(firstname,lastname,age,gender,email)`
- `Scraps(email,scrap,posttime)`
- `requests(email,frnemail,frnshpstatus,frnpic)`

I want a query that connects these three tables to show scraps posted by user and by the people whose frnshpstatus is 'Y' with respect to his his email in request table.

Comment: You need to be a little more specific with your database structure. Might there be multiple requests for the same user in the request table? It would be helpful to know how you see the structure of the output looking. Do you want a list of people in the request column or would that be separate from the main query?

Comment: I just want the structure of my scraps like facebook. The problem of multiple requests has been sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a join query.

```
DECLARE @usrEmail varchar(255) // Set the users email you are getting.

SELECT l.*, s.scrap, s.posttime
FROM Login l
LEFT JOIN Scraps s
ON l.email = s.email
WHERE l.email = @usrEmail

// Use a UNION query to also get scraps left by the users friend.
// Im assuming the friends would have entries in the login column as well.
UNION ALL

SELECT l.*, s.scrap, s.posttime
FROM Login l
LEFT JOIN Scraps s
ON l.email = s.email
WHERE l.email IN (SELECT frnshpEmail FROM requests WHERE email = @usrEmail AND frnshpStatus = 'Y') // This will create a list of all the users that are also have a frnshp with the user.
```

I'm not sure how you are using the requests table. If you can give me more details, I'll try to help with the specifics, but with what I have, this should give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: Defaul frnshp status is n now the user send frnrqst to to the othe user than if it accepts his request than there is uptade query for request table." Update requests set frnshpstatus='Y' where Email='" + Session["UserName"] + "' And frnemail='" + str + "'"" . request table has coloumns [Email]
      ,[frnemail]
      ,[message]
      ,[frnshpstatus]
      ,[frnpic]
      ,[frnshpdate]

Comment: I modified the query to use a UNION query to get all scraps from friends of the initial user.

Comment: I would try to use a variable rather than concatenating a string. It helps tremendously when trying to avoid sql injections.

Comment: Thank you sir these answer is much more helpful but it is just showing the scraps posted by user's friends but not the scraps posted by him himself.

Comment: Are you sure you grabbed both queries? There are two joined with a UNION statement. The first one will get scraps from the user, the second will get the scraps from friends.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from scraps where email in(
select r.frnemail
from [Login] l inner join requests r
on l.email=r.email and r.frnshpstatus = 'Y'
where l.email=@useremail)
```

Comment: here create the variable  @useremail and set the value